# Change middle value of a input[type=range]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a input[type=range] whre the minValue is 500 and the maxValue is 250000.
I need the middle of the slider to be 20000 that means having two different and visually the middle will be 20000. How can i do this?

```
const inputLoanRef = React.useRef(null);
const [minLoanValue, setMinLoanValue] = React.useState(0);
const [maxLoanValue, setMaxLoanValue] = React.useState(0);
const [step, setStep] = React.useState(5000);
const [loan, setLoan] = React.useState<number>(20000);
const styleLoanInput = {
 background: `linear-gradient(90deg, ${active} 0% ${progressLoan},
 ${inactive} ${progressLoan} 100%)`,
};

<input
  ref={inputLoanRef}
  id="sliderId"
  className="inputR"
  name="sliderName"
  type="range"
  min={minLoanValue}
  max={maxLoanValue}
  step={step}
  value={loan}
  onChange={handleLoanChange(minLoanValue, maxLoanValue)}
  style={styleLoanInput}
/>
```

```
  const handleLoanChange = (min, max) => (event) => {
    const num = event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9,-]+/g, '').replace(',', '.');
    const value = loanLogic(Number(num));
    let inputs = document.getElementById("sliderId");

    if (value < middleValue)
      setStep(20000);
    else
      setStep(500);
    const progress = (value / max) * 100 + '%';
    setLoan(value);
    const payload = {
      RequestedCreditAmount__c: value,
    };
    store.dispatch(setLeadData({...store.getState().lead, ...payload}));
    const newBackgroundStyle = `linear-gradient(90deg, ${active} 0%
       ${progress}%,
       ${inactive} ${progress}% 100%)`;
    inputLoanRef.current.style.background = newBackgroundStyle;
  };
```

I tried change steps from 500 to 20000 and 20000 to 250000 but didn't worked as expected

Comment: Are you wanting to have the maxValue be 250000 and the minValue to be 500, but have the middle of the slider appear to be 20000? I don't think that's how this input works. The middle is going to be 125000; to get something else to happen you could either hack it together by changing the max value to be 40000, or make something totally custom that has a non-linear scale, like this: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/#non-linear-scale